# Is there a way to receive a notification/callback if network proxy settings change in OSX/iOS?

Tags: ios, macos, proxy, notifications

I want to receive a notification/callback if network proxy settings change in OSX/iOS (C, C++, or Objective C)?  Does anyone have examples on how to do this?

Comment: Try researching NSNotification class reference, here is the link. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 3):

Monitor the System Configuration with `SCDynamicStoreSetNotificationKeys()`. For the keys you need to watch for, see the [System Configuration Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/SystemConfigFrameworks/SC_UnderstandSchema/SC_UnderstandSchema.html). See `SCDynamicStoreCreateWithOptions()` for how to set up an `SCDynamicStore` object, along with the notification callbacks.